# Append data in list

Tags: c#, list, enums, append

```
public enum ParameterData
{
    value = 0,
    value1,
    value2,
    value3,
    value4,
    value5
}

List<ParameterData> data = new List<ParameterData>();
data.Add(ParameterData.value);
data.Add(ParameterData.value1);
data.Add(ParameterData.value2);
data.Add(ParameterData.value3);
data.Add(ParameterData.value4);
data.Add(ParameterData.value5);

int i = data.Count;
List<byte> result = new List<byte>();
for (int j = 0; j <= i; j++)
{
    result.AddRange(p.GetParamaterVal((ParameterData)j));
}

public byte[] GetParamaterVal(ParameterData id)
{
    List<byte> data = new List<byte>();
    switch (id)
    {
        case ParameterData.value:
            data.AddRange(BitConverter.GetBytes(0));
            break;
        case ParameterData.value1:
            data.AddRange(BitConverter.GetBytes(1));
            break;
        case ParameterData.value2:
            data.AddRange(BitConverter.GetBytes(2));
            break;
        case ParameterData.value3:
            data.AddRange(BitConverter.GetBytes(3));
            break;
        case ParameterData.value4:
            data.AddRange(BitConverter.GetBytes(4));
            break;
        case ParameterData.value5:
            data.AddRange(BitConverter.GetBytes(5));
            break;
    }

    return data.ToArray();
}
```

Here GetParamaterVal method is returning byte array. this byte array should return all the parameter value but according to my current implementation it's giving me only the one paramter data at a time.

but I want whole parameter data in one byte array. It's mean whenever it will match with one case, store data in list and go for other case it will append data in existing list data.

Please tell me how can I do this.

Comment: " this byte array should return all the parameter value " this is very unclear; can you give a concrete example? i.e. if I pass `ParameterData.value3`, what do you **want** it to return, and by what reasoning?

Comment: I have to send all data to other application. For that I have created this byte array. First time I have to send all data(enum member, I have property for all member in enum) and next time user can query for any data at a time. but when First time I have to send all data for that I have to add this data in list. Hope I'm clear now.

Comment: Nope, still not really very clear; again: if I pass `ParameterData.value3`, what return value are you looking for?

Comment: OK when we pass parameterData.value3 on that time it should append this value with value of parameterData.value, parameterData.value1, parameterData.value2.

Comment: And what do *you* think that means, in bytes? i.e. if you had to write a `byte[]` of your expected return from `ParameterData.value3`, what would it be? For example (intentionally not related to the question), if `[42, 128, 217, 0, 5]` expresses a random 5 bytes: what would `GetParameterVal(ParameterData.value3)` return?